# Wordpress shortcode fires api call when editing post

Tags: php, api, wordpress, shortcode

I created a wordpress plugin with a add_shortcode filter that sends an api call to our system and retrieves documents from the server. However, I noticed that it fires even in the Admin area while I am editing a post or a page. So as I type the value inside the shortcode, it continuously communicates with the server.

How do I stop the shortcode from firing the api call function unless it was published in the post/page?

### Edit- Adding more info

The comments below are putting me on the right track, so I want to add more info for you guys.

I am using the WordPress Boilerplate. I added the add_shortcode filter to the plugin library and I register the add_shortcode in the define_public_hook:

```
$this->loader->add_shortcode( 'my_plugin', $plugin_public, 'my_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

then in my-plugin-public-display.php I add the functions (I'll abbreviate it...):

```
public function api_get_as_json( $controller, $slug, $action, $params, $endpoint ) {

        if ( null == $params ) {
            $params = array();
        }

        // Create URL with params
        $url = $endpoint . $controller . $slug . $action . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        // echo $url;

        // Use curl to make the query
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array(
            $ch, array( 
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            )
        );

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // Decode output into an array
        $json_data = json_decode( $output, true );

        curl_close( $ch );

        return $json_data;
    }

    /**
     * Shortcodes
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     */

    public function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
        //turn on output buffering to capture script output
        ob_start();

        // Get attributes from shortcode
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
            ...
        ), $atts, 'my_plugin' );

        $my_array = //getting the array attributes here...

        /* Send API calls to WhoTeaches, get profile and Packages */
        $result = $this->api_get_as_json('controller/', null, 'action', $my_array, $host . "domain.com/api/v1/");

        // Load the view
        include (plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'public/partials/my-plugin-public-display.php');

        // Get content from buffer and return it
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;

        // Clear the buffer
        ob_end_flush();
    }
```

Do I need to add or edit something here?

Comment: You could maybe start by finding the JS/jQuery code making those calls ?

Comment: If its a shortcode i don't see why it will be fired while publishing a post, maybe the way you registered it ? anyway you can check if not `is_admin()` to your shortcode callback function.

Comment: I thinking @Amin.T is on the right track. Does your shortcode make the API call when the shortcode is registered as apposed to when the shortcode is used? WordPress makes AJAX calls to save drafts of your post as you edit it. While WordPress wouldn't process your shortcode during that request it would register the shortcode unless you've told it not to.

Comment: @Amin and Lucas, thanks for the comments, I can indeed add an if statement, which I will unless there is a better solution. I edited my post and added details about the add_shortcode function I am using. Could you please have a quick look?

Comment: i think there is an issue with the loader `add_shortcode` functions, not sure what, however can you try to do it another way : `$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'yourpluginname_register_shortcodes' );` and then `public function yourpluginname_register_shortcodes(){
      function your_shortcode($atts){
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                //your options
        ), $atts ) );
        //do your plugin stuff
      }
      add_shortcode("your-shortcode-name", "your_shortcode");
    }` and let us know.

Comment: @Amin my loader function is pretty basic: I add it to the public function __construct() { $this->actions = array(); $this->filters = array(); $this->shortcodes = array();} then declare it as public function add_shortcode( $tag, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 2) { $this->shortcodes = $this->add( $this->shortcodes, $tag, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );} and finally call it at run: foreach ( $this->shortcodes as $hook ) { add_shortcode( $hook['hook'], array( hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );}